# Could not parse the remainder: '{%get(gender='F')%}.fullname' from 'x.parent.{%get(gender='F')%}.fullname'

Tags: django, django-templates, django-4.1

I have a problem with getting a data in template. I am writing code in python file its working.

```
  students = Student.objects.all()
  for x in students:
    print(x.parent.get(gender='M').fullname)
```

It gets me `Parent Fullname`, but when i write it in template like:

```
{% for x in students %}
  <td class="small d-none d-xl-table-cell  text-center">{{ x.parent.{%get(gender='F')%}.fullname }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

it gets me `Could not parse the remainder: '{%get(gender='F')%}.fullname' from 'x.parent.{%get(gender='F')%}.fullname'` error. I tried write it like `{{ x.parent.get(gender='F').fullname }}` but i get same error

Same code working in python file but not working in template.

Comment: You can't do that: Django's template language is *deliberately* limited to prevent people from writing business logic in the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that: Django's template language is *deliberately* limited to prevent people from writing business logic in the template.

You can define this in the `Student` model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    # …

    @property
    def mother(self):
        return self.parent.get(gender='F')

    @property
    def father(self):
        return self.parent.get(gender='M')
```

Then you use:

```
{{ x.mother }}
```

in the template.

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the manager to fetch the related objects in reverse. Therefore
> normally the `related_name` of a `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField` is *plural*,
> for example `parents` instead of <s>`parent`</s>.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include `{% %}` bracket inside `{{ }}` bracket. You cannot simply use all Pythonish logic inside templates. Template engine can process only some simple things. For more complicated logic you can use custom tags, but first read: [Django DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/)